# Android streaming text

Tags: android, http, download, streaming

I'm creating app that has to show live position of some vehicles. Their position is obtained by GPS via Rasberry PI, is sent to my server and there it is converted to Json file. Then on android device I am creating app which converts this file and lets user see vehicle position.

I am downloading it via HTTP protocol, and I think it is good way of solving problem. But my boss is insisting that it could be done by streaming (because, as he says, it is not neceserry to download data from server when vehicle is not moving for about 30 minutes), SO.

What is the way of creating a situation in which android device is not downloading data but waiting for server to send data? Is it even possible?
As far as I know, streaming is constantly sending data to target device, and device is constantly receiving this data.
The only way I can think about is to create server on every android device, send server data to my server (IP, port etc.) and from my server connect to every device and send position only when vehicle is moving - but this is costfull and not proper way I think.

Any ideas or help?

Comment: Have you considered using push notifications?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle your problem is implementing a GCM and dealing with PUSH NOTIFICATIONS.

- If connection is not available at the moment, will be sent when connection will be ok.
- If the receiver isn't available at the moment, same things will happen.
- It consumes less resources than constantly http calls.

See more information at https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html